# Non-parametric 2-sample test for correlated data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, autocorrelation

I have two samples of data, S1 and S2, that both suffer from spatial autocorrelation. The samples are different sizes and are not paired (specifically, S1 is comprised of M subsamples of k spatially correlated data points, while S2 contains N of these subsamples).

The data are mostly continuous, however, due to the quantity being measured, there are some values which are undefined but known to be high compared to the rest of the sample, and have been set to fixed artificially high values. For this reason, only median statistics can be used and whitening the data using the covariance matrix is not possible.

I would like to check if S1 and S2 come from the same population, however I am unable to find something non-parametric that works with correlated data. I was wondering if anyone is aware of a test that could be applicable in this situation.

Comment: Would you consider 'robust' rather than 'nonparametric', or must it be nonparametric?